# What happened to Colt after the Chimera Ant Arc?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Reina reunited with her mom at the end of Chimera Ant Arc, but does Colt ever get to reunite with his mom in the manga, or does he stay with (girl) Kite? Also, when Colt met his mother while the chimera ants were hunting for humans, did he know that was his mother when he was a human?